Does G-d experience pain?
I am trying to think through how He could create the universe, filled with pleasure and pain (heaven and hell), and yet not experience all of it together? In His infinite oneness, permeating all of creation, He would seemingly have to empathize with His creation, and therefore feel pain, and yet at the same time be beyond pain and pleasure somehow. But if the infinite oneness is perfected, or in "perfect harmony and balance", wouldn't that mean He only experiences either pure pleasure or pure peace, and so be located on one side of the pain-peace-pleasure spectrum? Or would it mean He experiences the full spectrum at once, and therefore knows complete pain and complete pleasure, or something like that?
What is the Jewish / Kabbalah perspective on this?

https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0106.htm#6

why are you trying to assign human qualities and emotions to God?

@rosends that comment seems to be lacking context? "why are you trying to ask the question that you are asking"?

@rosends I wasn't ascribing a human emotion, my working theory from the outside is that pain-peace-pleasure was the ultimate foundation of existence, but perhaps G-d is outside of experiencing anything I guess? To me this spectrum was like a mathematical+awareness thing. Also, pain (at least what I'm referring to) is not an emotion.

You know when people say "you don't have to let them hurt you, it's your choice". This is because your essential self is unaffectable - you are a free being. Only you can affect yourself. This is part of the philosophy of essence, which is a philosophy that is not controversial either among the philosophers of Chakira, or the Kabbalists, or the Chassidim who tried to resolve both camps into a unified teaching.
If a person is a man of strength by Torah standards, then he is able to retain this "unaffected" state, and decide, using his own leadership and initiative, based on his own decision, how to feel about anything and everything (and if he is Kadosh, it will be in line with Torah always). As Ben Zoma states in Avot 4:1:

Who is strong? He who conquers his inclination,
as it is said: “He that is slow to anger is better than the mighty;
and he that rules his spirit than he that takes a city” (Mishlei 16:32)

The Rambam states in the Moreh that attributing human emotions, and things like pain and pleasure to Hashem is nonsensical. Human feelings are reactive, instinctive creations that affect someone, and are also very lowly - definitely non-applicable to Hashem. Hashem's knowledge of our pain, however, is His self knowledge. All is indeed one with Him, like you state, and He knows it with a perfect knowledge (Mishneh Torah). This perfect knowledge is also not something we can describe as "Hashem experiencing" either, according to Rambam. "Experiencing" is a human way of looking at things (too lowly for Hashem, and also implies He is being affected).
The Kabbalist the Maharal takes this a step further in Gevurot Hashem, and states that even knowledge is not "His Essence". Similar to the Moreh, claiming that Hashem "knows" in any way that we can conceive or express is incorrect, and the sublime truth of the matter is level upon level of sublime loftiness, removed from our understanding or grasp. Knowledge, as we know it, is just a creation to Hashem, as distant from His Essence as a stone or physical action is.
The Ramak (teacher of the Arizal) resolves this in Pardes Rimonim by saying that both are correct (and built upon by the Tzemach Tzedek in Derech Mitzvotecha). The Rambam, when he talks about Hashem being the Knower, the Knowledge and the Known, in a great oneness of knowledge that is beyond our comprehension and our ability to utter or hear, is referring to the Sefirot of Atzilut. From Hashem's point of view, these are indeed as lowly as pebbles, but from our point of view, loftier than the mind can comprehend, infinite and ineffable.
Despite that, they are created from Godliness, and He identifies with them. So when we say Hashem knows, it is appropriate to say He knows with His Chochma. We can therefore say that what He knows can indeed be pain. It can be the pain of humanity, or it can be pain relevant to the Sefirot of Atzilut themselves. The former is just a mashal of a mashal of the latter, and the latter is a tzimtzum of true Godliness.

ובפרט מצד מקור נשמותינו
And specifically, [how much more so does the pain we share in our
unified souls be felt] by the Source of our souls (Derech Mitzvotecha Isur Sinat Yisrael, Mitzvat Ahavat Yisrael 1:1)

Another source is in Tomer Devorah, by the Ramak, by the fourth Midda of Rachamim:

והינו לשארית נחלתו לשון שאר בשר וסוף סוף הם נחלתו. ומה אמר, אם אענישם
הרי הכאב עלי כדכתיב (ישעיה סג, ט) בכל צרתם לו צר.
This, too, is the meaning of the words "the she'erit [remnant] of His
heritage," implying she'er basar, a blood relationship. In the final
analysis, the children of Israel are God's inheritance. Says the Holy
One, Blessed be He: "If I punish them, the pain is Mine!", as it is
written, "In all their trouble, He is afflicted..." (Yeshayahu 63:9).

The Ramak goes on to prove that the pain is His, and not limited to a particular Sefira or level of the Seder Hishtalshelus (the spiritual cosmos, including His revelations within it).
Now to finish where we started. He can also choose whether on not to actually be hurt or not. We can't affect Him, He is Mighty. But don't limit Hashem, He is beyond limit (even beyond the limit of being beyond limit! See Maamarim Yom Tov shel Rosh HaShana 5666 p. 167). Woe unto the person who does something and Hashem decides to let it hurt Him, because it is a true contradiction to His Essence that He cannot abide by! Generally, it seems that what He lets hurt Him, because it is a perfection to do so, is when He doesn't have us, because we sinned, or abandoned Him. We are His afterall, so this is the biggest violation of His Essence.

Note, I did not address the pain-peace-pleasure spectrum because I do not know if that correlates to any valid Jewish idea. It doesn't sound so, but then again I never heard it before. Note: it might even be comparative religion. I've noted you have a thirsty mind for true knowledge of Hashem and reality, and may I recommend that thinking of questions and asking them here is not the right way to make good progress. One should study Torah in an authentic way, and this is something that takes years, hard work, and progress isn't always the same for all. One must also get rid of preconceptions

The pain-peace-pleasure idea is just something I thought of when I had a deep spiritual experience, and trying to boil it down to some mathematical thing that the quantum world might be built out of , so definitely probably not heard of it. I am a religious studies / neurobiology double major from UC Berkeley, and have looked at Buddhism, Judaism, Hinduism, Christianity, Islam, Zoroastrianism, Sikhism, Egyptian, Native American Religions, Mesoamerican Religions, and of course Latin/Greek philosophies. So I'm spiraling toward the proper direction it seems, slowly.

Thank you for your answer(s), I will have to let all of this deeply sink in.

@Lance are you Jewish? If so I will try to direct you to studying this in the correct way. Doing otherwise will be very destructive

@Lance Let us take this to chat

Hello Lance and welcome to Mi Yodeya.
Your instinct and reason about this subject are aimed in the right direction.
The general rule from the traditional Jewish viewpoint (including Kabbalah) is that G-d is one. This implies consequentially that nothing from the created universe which we experience and perceive through our senses is separate and apart from G-d.
But like you raise in your question, doesn't that mean that in terms of how we understand and experience the universe, that there must be some kind of deficiency with G-d if G-d is not lacking what we experience?
To this, we have a teaching from Elijah the Prophet, who explains to us in regard to G-d, that G-d's thoughts (and consequentially G-d's emotions, feelings, etc., which arise from intellect according to the order implanted and imbued throughout all of creation by the Creator) are not like our thoughts. The Prophet uses similar Hebrew words sharing a common word root, which means they have a common meaning but are categorically different (like for example חכים ולא בחכמה ידיעא, מבין ולא בבינה ידיעא, Wise and not with known Wisdom, Understanding and not with known understanding), to distinguish our experience from G-d.

The Mishnah (Sanhedrin 6:5), as printed, seems to indicate that God does participate in human pain:

אָמַר רַבִּי מֵאִיר, בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁאָדָם מִצְטַעֵר, שְׁכִינָה מַה הַלָּשׁוֹן אוֹמֶרֶת כִּבְיָכוֹל, קַלַּנִי מֵרֹאשִׁי, קַלַּנִי מִזְּרוֹעִי. אִם כֵּן הַמָּקוֹם מִצְטַעֵר עַל דָּמָם שֶׁל רְשָׁעִים שֶׁנִּשְׁפַּךְ, קַל וָחֹמֶר עַל דָּמָם שֶׁל צַדִּיקִים.
Rabbi Meir said: The phrase “for he that is hung is a curse [kilelat] of God” should be understood as follows: When a man suffers in the wake of his sin, what expression does the Divine Presence use? I am distressed [kallani] about My head, I am distressed about My arm, meaning, I, too, suffer when the wicked are punished. From here it is derived: If God suffers such distress over the blood of the wicked that is spilled, even though they justly deserved their punishment, it can be inferred a fortiori that He suffers distress over the blood of the righteous.

However, if one looks in Rambam's commentary one will see that he possessed a different text of the Mishnah (which omits שכינה) which does away with such a connotation. It jives well with Rambam's notion of a transcendent God.
(מה הלשון אומרת כלומר איזה דבר הוא מנהג בני אדם לומר כשהוא רוצה לענות מי שמצטער בצערו אין הנאה בזה המעשה ולא בהנחתו והדברים שהיו אומרים בימי ר"מ קלני מראשי קלני מזרועי כך אמר הכתוב שבמיתת זה החוטא יש חורבן המציאות ולהניח אותו בחיים אין טוב ואם זה אומר במחויב מיתה כ"ש מי שנהרג נקי)

Great, thanks. Can you briefly allude to what G-d does experience, if He experiences anything at all? Because I was under the assumption G-d at least experienced, but perhaps I was completely wrong. And I'd like to avoid having to ask another poorly-received question .

@Lance "Can you briefly allude to what G-d does experience" - it is a strong principle of Judaism that one cannot know what it's "like" to be Hashem, and describe His "experience" in positive terms

@RabbiKaii Ok got it, thanks.

True, in the Rambam's text it's not God saying "my head and arm," but the Mishnah is still referring to God, whether or not the text has the word שכינה in the first part. This is an interpretation of כי קללת א' תלוי and it says אם כן המקום מצטער (although the Rambam's text according to Mechon Mamre: אם כך אמר הכתוב מצטער אני, but "I" in the Torah is God). So either way the Rambam must have understood the text to mean that God (represented by the Torah's קללת=קלני) is in distress. And so he explains what it means for God to be in distress in non-corporeal terms:שבמיתת זה החוטא יש חורבן המציאות

@b a The PhM text I quoted (from Sefaria) has בני אדם expressing their pain for someone they care about (that they are מצטער about—not when a person is in pain as the plain reading has it) that needs to be punished. This aphorism is said amongst people (not the Shechinah). When Rambam carries it over to the pasuk he does it in a way which negates any emotion on behalf of God. I'm not saying it nec flows the smoothest but it's fairly obvious what Rambam is trying to accomplish here . .

@Nahum Right, the saying is said amongst people. But it has to be saying something analogous about God because the purpose of this statement is to explain, what does קללת אלהים mean? And the answer is that it means the sensation קלני. Without making the connection between קללת and קלני Rabbi Meir's statement has nothing to do with the context. Of course, the Rambam interprets the "sensation" of קלני in a non-corporeal way (שבמיתת...), but this is due to his interpretation and not to his text (and conversely our text doesn't imply any more than his that God experiences a corporeal kind of pain)

We use a lot of anthropomorphism to describe God (ie. putting things in human terms) because it helps us relate to an infinite being, but we have to be conscious that this isn't reflective of reality.
I'd say that you are looking at this in limited human terms.  Experiencing pain and emotions is very much tied to a physical body.  I would say that God doesn't experience emotions by definition as emotions are necessarily something that imposes a change and even a restriction on the person experiencing them, and these are therefore things that cannot apply to God.
That is not to say that He is uncaring. He has a total understanding of what it is like for us to experience pain and emotions, but I wouldn't use the word "empathy" or even "sympathy" to describe that as I feel that is also putting it too much in human terms.
In terms of pleasure, peace, pain and any other emotion, He knows what it is like to experience these because He has perfect knowledge.  That doesn't mean that He actually does experience them, at least not in the same way that we do.
